# Proof of compound distribution Negative Binomial compound with Binomial

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose $Y \sim Negative \,Binomial \, (\mu, \theta) $
$X|Y \sim Binomial \, (Y, p) $ (with $\mu, \theta, p$ constant).

What is the distribution of $X$ ? I think $X$ must be Negative Binomial ($\mu_X, \theta_X$) with $\mu_X = \mu.p$ and $\theta_X = \theta$ but can't prove it fully.

My proof is as follow:

> $P(Y = y) = \frac{\Gamma(\theta+y)}{\Gamma(\theta).y!} . \frac{\mu^y . \theta^\theta}{(\mu + \theta)^{\mu + \theta}}$  (1)

> $P(X = x | Y = y) = \binom{y}{x} . p^x . (1-p)^{y-x}$
> $P(X = x, Y = y) = P(X = x | Y=y). P(Y=y)$

> Sum over $y = x \to \infty$ we have the marginal distribution of $X$:
> $P(X) = \frac{\theta^\theta . p^x . \mu ^ x}{\Gamma(\theta) \, x! \, (\mu + \theta)^{\theta}} \sum \limits_{y = x}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(\theta + y) \, \mu^{y-x} \, (1-p)^{y-x}}{(\mu + \theta)^y \, (y-x)!}$

From now, I'm stuck and don't know how to manipulate the $\sum$ part to arrive at the answer.

If you have any idea or suggestion of proof, it would be very nice to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: what do you mean for Negative binomial? there are 2 different parametrizations for that density...one counting the trials and another one counting the failures

Comment: @tommik: hi, thanks for your comment, it is another way to parameterize the negative binomial distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution, please have a look at this link, at the part #alternative formulations

Comment: I GOT IT!!! X is negative binomial with parameters $\mu$, $\frac{\theta}{\theta+p(1-\theta)}$. Do you want the solution?

Comment: @tommik: you made my day, i have stuck at this question for 1 week, it would be nice if you can spend some time write up the answer. But it seems to me that the expectation of $X$ should  be $p. \mu$ right, it is quite obvious, intuitively.

Comment: I will post the sketch. The procedure is always the same but need some manipualtions...Thought it for 15 minutes before getting the solution....please wait, I'm writing it down but I'm still working at the same time :)...I'm not a mathematician, I'm only an amateur

Comment: @tommik: thank you very much, you are amazing. and, we are all mathematician right =)). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler approach is to work with probability generating functions.

Let $$\begin{align}
\Pr[Y = y] &= \binom{\mu-1+y}{\mu-1} \theta^\mu (1-\theta)^y, \quad y \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots \}, \\
\Pr[X = x \mid Y] &= \binom{Y}{x} p^x (1-p)^{Y-x} = \binom{Y}{x} (1-p)^Y \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^x , \quad x \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, Y\}. \end{align}$$

Note that we have written the binomial PMF in such a way that will make subsequent calculations easier.

Then $$\mathcal P_Y(z) = \operatorname{E}[z^Y] = \sum_{y=0}^\infty z^y \Pr[Y = y] = \sum_{y=0}^\infty \binom{\mu - 1 + y}{\mu - 1} \theta^\mu ((1-\theta)z)^y ,$$ and if we let $\theta' = 1 - (1 - \theta)z$, then multiplying by $(\theta')^\mu$ and pulling out $\theta^\mu$ transforms the summand into the PMF of a negative binomial distribution with parameters $\mu$ and $\theta'$; hence $$\mathcal P_Y(z) = \left(\frac{\theta}{\theta'}\right)^\mu = \left(\frac{\theta}{1 - (1-\theta)z}\right)^\mu.$$

A similar trick applies for the binomial PGF:  $$\mathcal P_{X \mid Y}(z) = \operatorname{E}[z^X \mid Y] = \sum_{x=0}^Y \binom{Y}{x} (1-p)^Y \left(\frac{pz}{1-p}\right)^x.$$  So if we let $p'$ satisfy $p'/(1-p') = pz/(1-p)$, or $$p' = \frac{pz}{1-(1-z)p},$$ then multiplying by $(1-p')^Y$ and pulling out $(1-p)^Y$ transforms the summand into a binomial PMF with parameters $Y$ and $p'$; thus $$\mathcal P_{X \mid Y}(z) = \left(\frac{1-p}{1-p'}\right)^Y = (1 - (1-z)p)^Y.$$

Now we are prepared to perform the desired calculation.  Note
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal P_X(z) &= \operatorname{E}[z^X] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[z^X \mid Y]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\mathcal P_{X \mid Y}(z)] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(1 - (1-z)p)^Y] \\
&= \mathcal P_Y(1 - (1-z)p) \\
&= \left(\frac{\theta}{1 - (1-\theta)(1 - (1-z)p)}\right)^\mu \\
&= \left(\frac{\frac{\theta}{p + (1-p)\theta}}{1 - \left(1 - \frac{\theta}{p (1-p)\theta}\right)z}\right)^\mu.
\end{align}$$
Hence $X$ is negative binomial with parameters $\mu$ and $$\theta' = \frac{\theta}{p + (1-p)\theta}.$$

Note that the derivation of the PGFs is optional, since these are well-known.  I have only included them here for convenience.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, get the joint pmf and sum w.r.t. $y$

$$\mathbb{P}(x,y)=\binom{\mu+y-1}{y}\binom{y}{x}\theta^\mu(1-\theta)^yp^x(1-p)^{y-x}$$

some esay passages that you know lead to

$$\frac{\theta^\mu p^x(1-\theta)^x}{x!(\mu-1)!}\sum_{y-x=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(\mu+y-1)!}{(y-x)!}[(1-\theta)(1-p)]^{y-x}$$

Here where I have been stuck for some minutes...but then I look at the known series founding this one

$$ \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x^i\binom{n+i}{i}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^{n+1}}
\qquad (1) 
}
$$

Thus I multiplied/divided my series for $(\mu+x-1)!$ finding

$$\frac{\theta^\mu p^x(1-\theta)^x(\mu+x-1)!}{x!(\mu-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\binom{(\mu+x-1)+k}{k}[(1-\theta)(1-p)]^{k}$$

That is using the known series (1) and after some easy simplifications

---

EDIT: intermediate passage

$$\frac{\theta^\mu[p(1-\theta)]^x}{x!(\mu-1)!}\frac{(\mu+x-1)!}{[1-(1-\theta)(1-p)]^{\mu+x}}$$

---

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\binom{\mu+x-1}{x}\left[ \frac{\theta}{1-(1-\theta)(1-p)} \right]^\mu\left[ \frac{p(1-\theta)}{1-(1-\theta)(1-p)} \right]^x$$

or

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\binom{\mu+x-1}{x}\left[ \frac{\theta}{\theta+p(1-\theta)} \right]^\mu\left[ \frac{p(1-\theta)}{\theta+p(1-\theta)} \right]^x$$

which is evidently a negative binomial $NB(\mu;\pi)$ where $\pi=\frac{\theta}{\theta+p(1-\theta)} $

I by-passed some passages but I think you will not have problem with this easy algebra

Comment: Could you please give me the source where you found the proof of the series (1) ? It seems that I stuck at that part but I don't know how to prove the (1). Many thanks

Comment: I found it in wikipedia (italian). Wiki english is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series link. The series is "binomial coefficent" , the second series, just slightly modified with mine but the same.

Comment: Hmm, if i used the series (1), my result will be $X$ is Negative Binomial ($\mu.p$ , $\theta$). I will check again and tell you if there is anything wrong.

Comment: added an intermediate passage... I will check them again but I think there are no errors in my calculations

Comment: hello, could you please tell me that you use which kind of parameterization of Negative Binomial distribution to calculate the joint pmf $P(x,y)$ ? I don't see any gamma function $\Gamma$ in your answer. Thank you

Comment: I used the NB you linked me in your comment above https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: It is strange. In fact, the equation (1) in my ask (i.e. the post) is indeed the definition of the pmf of $Y$ when we parameterize the Negative Binomial using $\mu$ and $\theta$. So confused @@

Comment: read carefully my answer, it is absolutely right and matches with @heropup result